# Selenium WebDriver not found when deploying Java application to Heroku

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, heroku, deployment, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing a Java application that uses Selenium WebDriver for web automation. Locally, everything works fine, but when I deploy the application to Heroku, I encounter an error related to the WebDriver not being found.

I've added the necessary Selenium dependencies to my pom.xml file and ensured that the correct versions are specified. I've also included the WebDriverManager dependency to handle the automatic setup of the WebDriver executable.

When I comment out the Selenium-related code and deploy the application to Heroku, it works correctly. However, when I uncomment the code and include the Selenium dependency, I receive the following error:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
```

Pom.xml file :

```
 <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.ceoBot.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Main.class :

```
<......>
 public static boolean foo() throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("some link");


        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='some.jpg']/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*"));

        if (!element.isSelected()) {
            element.click();
        }
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(144) + 1;
            WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//img/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*)[" + randomNumber + "]"));
            if (!elem.isSelected()) {
                elem.click();
            }
        }

        WebElement submitBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button"));
        submitBtn.click();

        WebElement finishBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a"));
        finishBtn.click();

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.quit();
        return true;
    }
<......>
```